# foreach taking too long time to bind the view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, foreach

I have a page which takes around 28-30 sec of load time. On performing various log operations I found that fetching data from database and then performing operation on it in controller takes at max 3 sec of time. Then it is passed to view in a foreach loop which takes around 25-28 sec to bind that. Why is that so? It is working fine in test environment (loads in 3-4 sec) but not in prod environment. No of records on both environment is 150.

```
foreach (var que in Model.category.RFP_Questions.Where(q => q.SubCategoryId == subcategpory.SubCategoryId))
{
   bool IsChecked = Model.category.RFP_SelectedQuestions.Any(sq => sq.QuestionId == que.QuestionId);
   <li class='@(IsChecked ? "bold-fonts" : "")'>
       <span>@que.Question</span>
   </li>
}
```

I figured out that the bool variable is taking too long as it gets assigned from .Any. Any alternative way to do that?

Comment: Is `Model` an Entity Framework entity?

Comment: we are using code first approach. fetching data using linq

Comment: you can use Contain Statement without while

Comment: I assume the answer is yes. You'll have to show the relevant classes (the actual entity that is `Model` and `Catetory` and `RFP_Questions`)

Comment: There is a call to the database, you should change the archtitecture and do it asyncron. Call the database and if the data there create yout elements. In the Test enviroment the database is local?

Comment: no. database is not local in test env also. and as i mentioned, database call and processing of data hardly takes 3 sec. its just view which is taking time.

Comment: If this is a 'real world' application (i.e not a hobby/personal app), then you should be using a view model and not directly accessing your database in the view. http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/how-do-i-implement-view-models-to-manage-data-for-aspnet-mvc-views